# I need to Optimize this Linq Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a Linq query that needs optimizing.

**Edit**

I guess over all what I am trying to do is select all the rows in the first table, but select the last or default row in Survey, CB and Science tables...

**Edit**

When this creates a query, I hit the database once for the entire query and then once more for EVERY single result I get back from the first query.  So if TestClass returns 30 results, I then hit the DB 30 more times for the Survey Object.

I really need a better way to make this work.

Thanks in advance!

**Example Query**

```
return (from xx in db.test                    
        select new TestClass                    {
        Added_By_User_ID = xx.Added_By_User_ID,
        Survey = (from ru in db.Utopia
                  where ru.Province_ID == xx.Province_ID
                  orderby ru.uid descending
                  select ru).Take(1).ToList(),
                }).ToList();
```

**Real Query**

```
return (from xx in db.Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_Gens
                where xx.Owner_Kingdom_ID == ownerKingdomID
                where kingdomList.Contains((Guid)xx.Kingdom_ID)
                select new ProvinceClass
                {
                    Kingdom_ID = xx.Kingdom_ID,
                    Kingdom_Island = xx.Kingdom_Island,
                    Kingdom_Location = xx.Kingdom_Location,
                    Owner_Kingdom_ID = xx.Owner_Kingdom_ID,
                    Province_ID = xx.Province_ID,
                    Province_Name = xx.Province_Name,
                    Owner_User_ID = xx.Owner_User_ID,
                    Race_ID = xx.Race_ID,
                    Updated_By_DateTime = xx.Updated_By_DateTime,
                    Networth = xx.Networth,
                    Land = xx.Land,
                    Monarch_Display = xx.Monarch_Display,
                    Owner = xx.Owner,
                    Sub_Monarch = xx.Sub_Monarch,
                    CB_Updated_By_Province_ID = xx.CB_Updated_By_Province_ID,
                    uid = xx.uid,
                    Formatted_By = xx.Formatted_By,
                    Utopian_Day_Month = xx.Utopian_Day_Month,
                    Utopian_Year = xx.Utopian_Year,
                    Ruler_Name = xx.Ruler_Name,
                    Personality_ID = xx.Personality_ID,
                    Nobility_ID = xx.Nobility_ID,
                    Money = xx.Money,
                    Daily_Income = xx.Daily_Income,
                    Food = xx.Food,
                    Runes = xx.Runes,
                    Population = xx.Population,
                    Peasents = xx.Peasents,
                    Peasents_Non_Percentage = xx.Peasents_Non_Percentage,
                    Trade_Balance = xx.Trade_Balance,
                    Building_Effectiveness = xx.Building_Effectiveness,
                    Military_Efficiency_Off = xx.Military_Efficiency_Off,
                    Military_Efficiency_Def = xx.Military_Efficiency_Def,
                    Draft = xx.Draft,
                    Soldiers = xx.Soldiers,
                    Soldiers_Regs_Off = xx.Soldiers_Regs_Off,
                    Soldiers_Regs_Def = xx.Soldiers_Regs_Def,
                    Soldiers_Elites = xx.Soldiers_Elites,
                    War_Horses = xx.War_Horses,
                    //Prisoners = xx.Prisoners,
                    Military_Net_Off = xx.Military_Net_Off,
                    Military_Net_Def = xx.Military_Net_Def,
                    Military_Current_Off = xx.Military_Current_Off,
                    Military_Current_Def = xx.Military_Current_Def,
                    Mil_Training = xx.Mil_Training,
                    Mil_Wage = xx.Mil_Wage,
                    Mil_Overall_Efficiency = xx.Mil_Overall_Efficiency,
                    Mil_Total_Generals = xx.Mil_Total_Generals,
                    Wizards = xx.Wizards,
                    Wizards_Value_Type = xx.Wizards_Value_Type,
                    Thieves = xx.Thieves,
                    Thieves_Value_Type = xx.Thieves_Value_Type,
                    Plague = xx.Plague,
                    Monarch_Vote_Province_ID = xx.Monarch_Vote_Province_ID,
                    Protected = xx.Protected,
                    Hit = xx.Hit,
                    Honor = xx.Honor,
                    Province_Notes = xx.Province_Notes,
                    CB_Export_Line = xx.CB_Export_Line,
                    Army_Out = xx.Army_Out,
                    Army_Out_Expires = xx.Army_Out_Expires,
                    Updated_By_Province_ID = xx.Updated_By_Province_ID,
                    SOM_Updated_By_Province_ID = xx.SOM_Updated_By_Province_ID,
                    SOM_Updated_By_DateTime = xx.SOM_Updated_By_DateTime,
                    CB_Updated_By_DateTime = xx.CB_Updated_By_DateTime,
                    CB_Requested = xx.CB_Requested,
                    CB_Requested_Province_ID = xx.CB_Requested_Province_ID,
                    SOM_Requested = xx.SOM_Requested,
                    SOM_Requested_Province_ID = xx.SOM_Requested_Province_ID,
                    SOS_Requested = xx.SOS_Requested,
                    SOS_Requested_Province_ID = xx.SOS_Requested_Province_ID,
                    Survey_Requested = xx.Survey_Requested,
                    Survey_Requested_Province_ID = xx.Survey_Requested_Province_ID,
                    Last_Login_For_Province = xx.Last_Login_For_Province,
                    Date_Time_User_ID_Linked = xx.Date_Time_User_ID_Linked,
                    Added_By_User_ID = xx.Added_By_User_ID,
                    NoteCount = (from yy in db.Utopia_Province_Notes
                                 where yy.Province_ID == xx.Province_ID
                                 select yy).Count(),
                    SOM = (from uu in db.Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_Type_Militaries
                           where uu.Province_ID == xx.Province_ID
                           where uu.Owner_Kingdom_ID == ownerKingdomID
                           where uu.DateTime_Added == (from ru in db.Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_Type_Militaries //datetime can be same for multiple items.
                                                       where ru.Province_ID == xx.Province_ID
                                                       where ru.Owner_Kingdom_ID == ownerKingdomID
                                                       orderby ru.uid descending // To get the last most inserted rows
                                                       select ru.DateTime_Added).FirstOrDefault()
                           select uu).ToList(),


                    SOS = (from zz in db.Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_Sciences
                           where ru.Province_ID == xx.Province_ID
                           where ru.Owner_Kingdom_ID == ownerKingdomID
                           orderby ru.uid descending
                           select ru).Take(1).ToList(),
                    Survey = (from ru in db.Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_Surveys
                              where ru.Province_ID == xx.Province_ID
                              where ru.Owner_Kingdom_ID == ownerKingdomID
                              orderby ru.uid descending
                              select ru).Take(1).ToList(),
                    CB = (from ru in db.Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_CBs
                          where ru.Province_ID == xx.Province_ID
                          where ru.Owner_Kingdom_ID == ownerKingdomID
                          orderby ru.uid descending
                          select ru).Take(1).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: You're doing a nested query so the behavior you are seeing is to be expected.  You'd get the same issue if you wrote similar SQL.  Simple nested queries can be replaced with joins, as Polity suggests.

Comment: You could eliminate the "sort-by, take one" queries by having this table link back to those tables by id.  Then you have a history, but you only have a single "current" value.  It is also a little weird to support a list, but make that list only have one value each.  I don't know about Linq to SQL, but in Linq to Entities, you can use `.Include("SomeProperty")` to force the data to be retrieved at the same time.  This only works if you have a province entity and appropriate DB FK relationships set up though.

Comment: @Merlyn, can you explain that a bit better?

Comment: Add a Latest_Survey_ID in your Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_Gens table.  Make it point to the latest entry.  Then just get that entry.  I don't know how LinqToSQL works, but in EF, with `Include`, that could let you eliminate round trips.  Here, at least it would make your query simpler.  It would require you to be careful when updating the survey table though, because you'd need to alter the province, and do so in a transaction.  You'd then need to worry about concurrent access...

Comment: If you wanted to eliminate that concurrency issue, you could introduce a province-to-latest-survey mapping table.  Then you don't have to worry about concurrency for anything but the mapping table.

Comment: Oh, and most DBAs would probably just tell you to stuff this in a view and/or sproc.

Answer (score 2):

You can select from your Utopia table and join the second one for getting the user_id like:

```
from ru in db.Utopia 
join xx in test on ru.Province_ID equals xx.Province_ID 
orderby ru.uid descending 
select new TestClass 
{ 
    Added_By_User_ID = xx.Added_By_User_ID, 
    Survey = ru
}
```

**Update for the real query**

This is one massive query, you should consider an approach based on joins as i suggested and based on local caching as Jim McKeeth suggested. Or you should create a new table all together.

When you need to query from multiple tables with optional data, you can perform a left join:

```
from ru in db.Utopia 
join user in db.Users on ru.UserId equals user.Id // User is required
join survey in db.Surveys on ru.Province_ID equals survey.Province_ID into j1
from survey in j1.DefaultIfEmpty() // Survey is optional (left join)
join address in db.Address on ru.UserId equals address.UserId into j2
from survey in j2.DefaultIfEmpty() // Address is optional (left join)
orderby ru.uid descending 
select new TestClass 
{ 
    Added_By_User_ID = xx.Added_By_User_ID, 
    Survey = survey,
    Street =  address.Street,
    UserName = new UserName
    {
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName
    }
}
```

Be aware that the amount of joins will influence the performance of your query. Sooner or later it will become more efficient do find a better way with caching.

Another note is that calling ToList() in your query will actually execute that part of the query (or the whole query).

Comment: @Scott - Try built it yourself first, it's a good exercise :)

Comment: I don't want to do one table all together because there can be many different Survey, Science, SOM and CB objects for one General Object even though I am only taking one object per each sub object.  So I think ive designed the tables well, just not the queries...

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
from xx in db.test
join ru in db.Utopia on xx.Province_ID equals ru.Province_ID
orderby ru.uid descending
select new ..
```

Comment: how do I get just the very last full RU table?  As you can see, I want the entire Survey in a brand new object...

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your real query to me indicates you should be moving this LINQ statement into a stored procedure, then calling that instead.

I recommend this because (a) you will have complete control over the how the query executes and, (b) profiling and performance optimizing your query is much easier in TSQL.  This is the strategy we have used in larger projects in the past when result-set generation becomes non-trivial.

I would also suggest you use AutoMapper to perform the task of transferring the sproc results into your DTO, because you appear to have a near 1:1 mapping

Comment: A view would also be a suitable wrapper.  You can join views.  Not sure if you can join sproc results without throwing them into a temporary table.

Comment: Good point. I think I would still go with a sproc, as it can return multiple result sets and would easily accomidate the cases above where he's fetching lists of items inline.

I can only imagine the ridiculously inefficient TSQL that has been generated to run this query!